# passing JSON data to a Spring MVC controller

Tags: json, jquery, spring-mvc, controller

I need to send a JSON string to Spring MVC controller.But I do not
 have any form bindings to it , I just need to send  a plain JSON data to Controller class.I am making jQuery AJAX call to the Controller method like the below code.

```
$.ajax ({
    url: "./save",
    type: "POST",
    data: JSON.stringify(array),
    dataType: "json",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    success: function(){
        alert("success ");
    }
});
```

But how do I retrieve it in the Controller method?(Note: It is just plain JSON data and not a form submission).

Answer (score 46):

Add the following dependencies

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId> 
    <artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId>
    <version>1.9.7</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId> 
    <artifactId>jackson-core-asl</artifactId>
    <version>1.9.7</version>
</dependency>
```

Modify request as follows

```
$.ajax({ 
    url:urlName,    
    type:"POST", 
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    data: jsonString, //Stringified Json Object
    async: false,    //Cross-domain requests and dataType: "jsonp" requests do not support synchronous operation
    cache: false,    //This will force requested pages not to be cached by the browser          
    processData:false, //To avoid making query String instead of JSON
    success: function(resposeJsonObject){
        // Success Message Handler
    }
});
```

Controller side

```
@RequestMapping(value = urlPattern , method = RequestMethod.POST)
public @ResponseBody Person save(@RequestBody Person jsonString) {

   Person person=personService.savedata(jsonString);
   return person;
}
```

`@RequestBody` - Covert Json object to java 
`@ResponseBody`- convert Java object to json

Comment: Please add ur assumptions about person

Comment: Person is a Normal POJO class. Here we are using the data of type Person.

Answer (score 7):

1. **Html**

   ```
   $('#save').click(function(event) {        
       var jenis = $('#jenis').val();
       var model = $('#model').val();
       var harga = $('#harga').val();
       var json = { "jenis" : jenis, "model" : model, "harga": harga};
       $.ajax({
           url: 'phone/save',
           data: JSON.stringify(json),
           type: "POST",           
           beforeSend: function(xhr) {
               xhr.setRequestHeader("Accept", "application/json");
               xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
           },
           success: function(data){ 
               alert(data);
           }
       });

       event.preventDefault();
   });
   ```

   2. **Controller**

      ```
      @Controller
      @RequestMapping(value="/phone")
      public class phoneController {

          phoneDao pd=new phoneDao();

          @RequestMapping(value="/save",method=RequestMethod.POST)
          public @ResponseBody
          int save(@RequestBody Smartphones phone)
          {
              return pd.save(phone);
          }
      ```
   3. **Dao**

      ```
      public Integer save(Smartphones i) {
          int id = 0;
          Session session=HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
          Transaction trans=session.beginTransaction();
          try {
              session.save(i);   
              id=i.getId();
              trans.commit();
          }
          catch(HibernateException he){}
          return id;
      }
      ```

Comment: Where does the .val() function come from?

Comment: I spent  a lot time to find out really good example. This is only one, which helped me a lot.

Answer (score 2):

You can stringify the JSON Object with JSON.stringify(jsonObject) and receive it on controller as String.

In the Controller, you can use the [javax.json](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/j/Downloadjavaxjson10jar.htm) to convert and manipulate this.

Download and add the .jar to the project libs and import the JsonObject.

To create an json object, you can use

```
JsonObjectBuilder job = Json.createObjectBuilder();
job.add("header1", foo1);
job.add("header2", foo2);
JsonObject json = job.build();
```

To read it from String, you can use

```
JsonReader jr = Json.createReader(new StringReader(jsonString));
JsonObject json = jsonReader.readObject();
jsonReader.close();
```