# send json object on form submit

Tags: java, jquery, json, forms

i have a usual form. the only thing i'm trying to differently is group 3 of the input values into a json. and when i click on submit, i want to send other inputs as usual but those 3 as one json. I have made it into json using jquery but unable to understand how to send it on submit click. Please see my code and let me know what's missing. (FYI i'm working on spring mvc)
i have this form:

```
    <form class="form-horizontal" action="success" method="post" role="form">
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="text" name="name" id="name" class="form-control" placeholder="Name" value="">
        <input type="text" name="dob" id="dob" class="form-control" placeholder="Date of Birth" value="">
    </div>

    <div class="row form-group">
        <div class="col-sm-3">
            <input type="text" id="school_name" class="form-control" placeholder="school/college name" />
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-3">
            <select class="form-control year" id="year">
<option>1</option>
<option>2</option>
</select>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-3">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="qualification" placeholder="qualification" />
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-3">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="add" value="add">Add More</button>
        </div>
    </div>

    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-danger form-control" id="save" value="Save">
</form>
```

and my jquery code is:

```
        $(document).on('click',"#save",function() {
        var $items = $('#school_name, #year,#qualification ')
        var education=null;
        var json = {}
        $items.each(function() {
            json[this.id] = $(this).val();
        });
        education= JSON.stringify(json);
        alert(education)    //this gives me the required result
        window.location="success?education="+education;  
// I guess something is wrong here
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First define id to your form `id='formId'`
and then you can get form data into JSON string with:

```
 var json = $("#formId").serialize();
```

The result would be:

```
school_name=college+name&year=1&qualification=good
```

You can pass the `json` string using ajax request:

```
 $.ajax({
     url: 'success',
     data: json
    })
    .then(function(response) {

    });
```

**Working example:**

```js
$(document).on('click',"#save",function() {

      var json = $("#formId").serialize();       
        alert(json)   
        
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form class="form-horizontal" action="success" method="post" role="form" id="formId">
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="text"  id="name" class="form-control" placeholder="Name" value="">
        <input type="text" id="dob" class="form-control" placeholder="Date of Birth" value="">
    </div>

    <div class="row form-group">
        <div class="col-sm-3">
            <input type="text" id="school_name" name="school_name" class="form-control" placeholder="school/college name" />
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-3">
            <select class="form-control year" id="year" name="year">
<option>1</option>
<option>2</option>
</select>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-3">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="qualification" name="qualification" placeholder="qualification" />
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-3">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="add" value="add">Add More</button>
        </div>
    </div>

    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-danger form-control" id="save" value="Save">
</form>
```

Comment: this is not how i want the output. i want to only make json of those 3 attributes i.e year,schoolname,qualification. not others.rest should remain same and be submitted in usual way

Comment: You can remove name="name" and name="dob"  from the inputs  and they will not be included to  json string. I will update the answer.

Comment: okay so when i serialize "#formID" it only serializes those input values which have "name" attribute in it..did i get it right?

Comment: yep, name="qualification" is the name of the attribute in json string: &qualification=good

Comment: okay! got it....but how does this json variable go to next page? the page that i go to after i click on submit btn

Comment: error: HTTP Status 400 - Required Json parameter 'json' is not present

Comment: i'm sorry if it seems spoon feeding...but can u edit ur code to use $("#formId").submit();

Comment: Can you send the @RequestMapping("/success") method at you controller?

Comment: @RequestMapping(value = "/success",method = RequestMethod.POST) 
 public ModelAndView first(@RequestParam("json")Json json) { 
  System.out.println(json);
  ModelAndView mv = new ModelAndView();
  mv.setViewName("success");
  return mv;
 }

Comment: @RequestParam("json")Json json is **wrong**. If you want to accept JSON you must use @RequestBody . Check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18524524/passing-json-data-to-a-spring-mvc-controller. Also check this tutorial about form submit using Spring mvc: http://www.baeldung.com/spring-mvc-form-tutorial

Answer (score 2):

It is not clear what type of data the server is expecting. Because, if the server accepts data in JSON, it simply cannot be sent using query params.

You may want to see [$.ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/). You can send your object `json` directly to the server using `data` key, like this:

```
$.ajax({
  url: 'success',
  data: json
})
.then(function(response) {
  // Handle the response here
});
```

It will simply send the data using query parameters to the server URL specified by `url` key. If your server accepts data in JSON instead, you may want to change the request method to `POST` and set the `contentType` to `json`, like this:

```
$.ajax({
  method: 'POST',
  url: 'success',
  contentType: 'application/json',
  data: json
})
.then(function(response) {
  // Handle the response here
});
```

Hope this clarifies your problem. For more details, observe the **Network** tab of your browser's developer tools to see how the data is being submitted to the server.

Answer (score 0):

here I have created a hidden field in your form named as education and while click save button it will generate JSON as you mention in question and assign it into education field then submit your form to `success` URL in post method

```js
$("document").ready(function(){

    $("#save").click(function(e){
    
        var $items = $('#school_name, #year,#qualification')
        var education=null;
        var json = {}
        $items.each(function() {
            json[this.id] = $(this).val();
        });
        education= JSON.stringify(json);
       $("#education").val(education);
    
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <form class="form-horizontal" action="success" method="post" role="form">
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="text" name="name" id="name" class="form-control" placeholder="Name" value="">
        <input type="text" name="dob" id="dob" class="form-control" placeholder="Date of Birth" value="">
    </div>

    <div class="row form-group">
        <div class="col-sm-3">
            <input type="text" id="school_name" class="form-control" placeholder="school/college name" />
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-3">
            <select class="form-control year" id="year">
<option>1</option>
<option>2</option>
</select>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-3">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="qualification" placeholder="qualification" />
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-3">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="add" value="add">Add More</button>
        </div>
    </div>

    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-danger form-control" id="save" value="Save">
    <input type="hidden" id="education" name="education">
</form>
```