# Spring MVC, pass json object to controler and return view with model attributes set

Tags: java, spring, jsp

I'm trying to send data to my controller, have it do a service call and then return the result to be displayed on the view

My Ajax call looks like this

```
$.ajax({
            url: "<c:url value="submitReportQuery"/>",
            type: "POST",
            dataType: "html",
            contentType: "application/json;",
            data: JSON.stringify(reportQueryMap),
            success: function (data) {
                $('#SelfServiceResults').html(data);
            }
        })
```

and my controller looks like this

```
@RequestMapping(value = "submitReportQuery", method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes="application/json" )
    public String submitReportQuery(@ModelAttribute Map<String, String> reportQueryMap/*, Model model, BindingResult bindingResult*/)throws Exception{
         //model.addAttribute("successful", true);
         return "queries/SelfServiceQueriesSubmitResults";
    }
```

The json object looks like this (it can have anything from 0-5 randomKeys) which I pass as a map to a service
Note: the actual name of "randomKey" can change the key is a unknown

```
{
"randomKey1":"111",
"randomKey2":"222",
"randomKey3":"333",
"reportType":"Commission Processed BH",
"reportProduct":"LIFE",
"reportMonth":"January 2017",
"queryRemark":"nice"
}
```

I can't seem to get the "successful" attribute passed to the view, if I add the parts comented out I get this error

```
org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Handler processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: java.lang.String submitReportQuery(java.util.Map)
```

I basically want [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18524524/passing-json-data-to-a-spring-mvc-controller) but it must return a view with attributes set on it

Comment: I think you should use `@RequestBody` rather than `@ModelAttribute`, and it would be better to use a class rather than a Map (just my thoughts).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@RequestMapping(value = "submitReportQuery", method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes="application/json" )
public String submitReportQuery(@RequestBody ReportQueryMapBean reportQueryMap)throws Exception{
     //model.addAttribute("successful", true);
     return "queries/SelfServiceQueriesSubmitResults";
}

public class ReportQueryMapBean {
    // to do delcare the bean fields to match the request
    // and corresponding getter and setter function
}
```

Comment: I get that same "java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: java.lang.String submitReportQuery(java.util.Map)" when trying this solution :(

Comment: you change ReportQueryMapBean  to Map<String, String>

Comment: I got it working with the ReportQueryMapBean, but all the values seem to be null

Comment: Try the below changes

  `public class ReportQueryMapBean  {
   private String randomKey1;
   private String randomKey2;
   private String randomKey3;
   private String reportType;
   private String reportProduct
   private String reportMonth;
   private String queryRemark;
   
   // to do add getter and setter method for the above fields
  }`