# Using generic JSON Object as Request Body

Tags: json, spring, angular, spring-mvc

I'm having a controller which receives JSON Object as input. But the problem is that, the content of JSON will vary for different requests, so Im not able to map the `RequestBody` to a POJO.
Is there a way I can specify the input parameter as generic `JSONObject` without having to specify a specific POJO.
I tried `@RequestBody JSONObject inputJson`. But this is throwing bad request from the client side.
I'm using spring 3.2.13 and Angular as Front End.
Any help is much appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It will depend a little on what you're using for JSON conversion. But you probably need to accept the input as a String and generate a JSONObject.

```
@RequestBody String inputJson
JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(inputJson);
```

Or process the input as a map and just use that directly. Most versions of Jackson will perform this conversion for you:

```
@RequestBody Map<String, Object> inputData)
 JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(inputData);
```

In the map case you may not need the JSONObject but you can generate it if you want.

Comment: While taking Map<String, Object> if the value of one property is very big in decimal, then it trims and convert it to double. How to solve that ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use JsonNode

```
@RequestBody JsonNode requestBody
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to convert the JSON as a string input and convert back to JSON? Check this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18524524/passing-json-data-to-a-spring-mvc-controller).