# Provide a POJO object as serialised string in REST API Request Payload

Tags: java, api, rest

I have a REST API uploadFeed that uploads the user feed based on feedType (string value taken input as part of the request body) . Different feedtype provides a different pojo model in the request body altogether.

For e.g If the feedType is lets say "TYPE1", then the API's request-body should look like the following:

```
{
 "feedType":"TYPE1",
 "inputModel": {
    "a": "somevalue"
    "b" : "somevalue",
    "c" : "somevalue",
  }
}
```

if the feedType is lets say "TYPE2", then the API's request-body should look like the following:

```
{
 "feedType":"TYPE2",
  "inputModel": {
    "x": "somevalue"
    "y" : "somevalue",
    "z" : "somevalue",
  }
}
```

Now I want to avoid providing different REST API endpoints for the two feedTypes. I am thinking of rather providing a serialised object of the inputModel as input and then deserialise at the backend based on the feedType. For .e.g

```
{
 "feedType":"TYPE2",
  "inputModel": "<<serialized object>>"
}
```

Is this a good REST API design or is there any better alternative.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can user [JSONObject](https://stleary.github.io/JSON-java/index.html)

accept json as string at api and parse it to JSONObject and user it as per your logic

```java
@RequestBody String jsonString
JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(jsonString);
```

More on JSONObject [here](https://www.baeldung.com/java-org-json) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51151695/7505731).

Answer (score 0):

You can create a class to map feedback request with `Map` field for `inputModel`,

```
class FeedbackRequest{
   String feedType;
   Map<String, String> inputModel;
   //getters setters
}
```