# AJAX/Spring MVC: JSON Object rendering in bracket notation in POST request

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, ajax, spring-mvc

**Why would a JSON be rendered in bracket notation when bound to a Web Request?**

I have an application that makes 2 REST Controller calls in a row.

First, an address is read from a form, serialized, AJAXed to a validation endpoint, and returned to the UI/JS as a Response object payload. This part works fine.

```js
$.ajax({
    method: 'POST',
    url: '/validate-shipping-address',
    data: $shippingInfoForm.serialize()
}
```

```java
    @PostMapping(path = "/validate-shipping-address")
    public RestResponse<Address> validateShippingAddress(
        @ModelAttribute("shippingForm") ShippingForm shippingForm) {

        return validateAddress(shippingForm.getAddress());
    }
```

If the response is successful, that payload (the address) is sent directly into the AJAX call for the second endpoint. This request blows up with a `400` and never enters the actual method.

```js
$.ajax({
    method: 'POST',
    url: '/shipping-stuff',
    data: {
            "shippingAddress": validationResponse.payload,
            "shipDate": shipDate,
            "csrfToken": csrfToken
    }
}
```

```java
@PostMapping(path = "/shipping-stuff")
public RestResponse<?> doShippingStuff(
    @RequestParam(name = "shippingAddress") Address shippingAddress,
    @RequestParam(name = "shipDate") @DateTimeFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd") Date shippingDate) {

    doStuff(); // Never hit
}
```

After much analysis, the issue is that Spring MVC cannot deserialize the address passed as an Address object. In the request, I see that the address fields are rendered as `address[city]`, `address[state]`, etc. instead of the standard dot notation `address.city`, `address.state` (as the first request has it). If I manually access them via the request using the bracket notation as the param name, it will pull out the value. e.g. `request.getParameter("address[city]");`.

When I use Chrome dev tools debugger to inspect the response from the first and the object entering the second AJAX call, they look like valid JSON. The Network:Form Data section in Chrome differs though - It shows the dot notation for the first, successful call and the bracket notation for the second, unsuccessful call.

Form Data (first call):

```
address.firstName=John&address.lastName=Doe&address.addressLine1=123+Main+St&address.city=New+York+City&address.state=NY&address.postalCode=12345&csrfToken=XXXX
```

Form Data (second call): (%5B = '[' and %5D = ']')

```
shippingAddress%5BfirstName%5D=John&shippingAddress%5BlastName%5D=Doe&shippingAddress%5BaddressLine1%5D=123+MAIN+ST&shippingAddress%5Bcity%5D=New+York+City&shippingAddress%5Bstate%5D=NY&shippingAddress%5BpostalCode%5D=12345&shippingAddress%5BzipFour%5D=6789&shipDate=2019-05-25&csrfToken=XXXX
```

So there really are 2 sub-questions:

(1) Is there something in the JS handling that would cause the address to be passed in the bracket form instead of the normal JSON form? I'd think if I could get around this then Spring MVC should work like normal.

(2) Is there a way to make Spring MVC able to handle this without resorting to `JSON.stringify` and then parsing with Gson/ObjectMapper directly in the controller code?

I've tried all permutations I can think of involving custom wrapper objects, `JSON.stringify`, `@RequestParam`, `@ModelAttribute`, and bare (no annotations). I also tried stringify-ing the whole AJAX payload and using `@RequestBody` on a wrapper object in the controller, but then the call fails as the [csrfToken](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33829607/631272) is not detected.

I've read through [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22649971/631272), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18524524/631272), and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16942193/631272), which informed the attempts above.

---

For now, I've worked around the issue with JSON.stringify and Gson (option 2 above), but would rather make Spring MVC do the work automatically.

Work around:

```js
$.ajax({
    method: 'POST',
    url: '/commercial-checkout/shipping-stuff',
    data: {
            "shippingAddress": JSON.stringify(shippingAddress),
            "shipDate": shipDate,
            "csrfToken": csrfToken
    }
});
```

```java
@PostMapping(path = "/shipping-stuff")
public RestResponse<?> doShippingStuff( //
    @RequestParam(name = "shippingAddress") String shippingAddressJson,
    @RequestParam(name = "shipDate") @DateTimeFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd") Date shipDate) {

    Address address = gson.fromJson(shippingAddressJson, AddressImpl.class);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As per your comment,

> I also tried stringify-ing the whole AJAX payload and using
>   @RequestBody on a wrapper object in the controller, but then the call
>   fails as the csrfToken is not detected.

When you use @RequestBody you need to create corresponding POJO object to deserialise your JSON. Also you need to add content-type property in your AJAX to indicate the server that you are sending an JSON.

```
$.ajax({
    method: 'POST',
    data: 'json',
    content-type: 'application/json',
    url: '/commercial-checkout/shipping-stuff',
    data: {
            "shippingAddress": JSON.stringify(shippingAddress),
            "shipDate": shipDate,
            "csrfToken": csrfToken
    }
});
```

Add a POJO as I mentioned,

```
public class AddressPOJO {

   shippingAddress,
   shipDate,
   csrfToken  

  //getter / setters
}
```

Modify your controller method,

```
@PostMapping(path = "/shipping-stuff", consumes = "application/json")
public RestResponse<?> doShippingStuff( @RequestBody  AddressPOJO addressPJO) {

    // do your logic..
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I did try a version of this, though I didn't include the csrfToken in the wrapper object. I also didn't set the content-type. I'll try it again with it and see if it works.